# How to Display the Texture after using ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshotAsTexture();

Tags: unity-game-engine

How do you display the actual ScreenCapture texture onto a public GameObject?

For example:

```cs
IEnumerator CaptureScreenShot()
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    Texture2D texture = ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshotAsTexture();
}
```

From this snippet, I've captured the screenshot, now I want to display this texture onto a public GameObject at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Simply apply it to a [RawImage](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-RawImage.html) component's [texture](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.RawImage-texture.html)

```c#
public RawImage _rawImage;

IEnumerator CaptureScreenShot()
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    Texture2D texture = ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshotAsTexture();

    _rawImage.texture = texture;
}
```

---

If you need it as `Sprite` for applying it to an `Image` or a `Material` you can also use [Sprite.Create](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.Create.html) like

```c#
Sprite mySprite = Sprite.Create(
    texture, 
    new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, texture.width, texture.height), 
    new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 
    100.0f
);
```